# Before_Body_End Catalog Pages Only Layout.xml

Tags: magento-1.8, layout, template

I'm looking to put a tracking script on all Catalog pages. `Search` Pages, `Category` (Layered & Non) and `Product_View`. Is there anyway to do this with Layout.xml? The best place for a script is `Before_Body_End` but I can only seem to access that from `<Default/>` which then does all the pages. Outside that, I can get it in the pages I mentioned but only before the footer starts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create the template file in app/design/frontend/[package]/[theme]/template/page/html/jsfooter.phtml and put the following

```
 <?php echo $this->getCssJsHtml() ?>
```

In `layout.xml` add the `<reference name="before_document_end">` as such replacing `your_script.js` with the location of your script in the theme's skin folder:

`Product View:`

```
<catalog_product_view translate="label">
    <reference name="root">
        <reference name="before_document_end">
            <block type="page/html_head" name="jsfooter" as="jsfooter" template="page/html/jsfooter.phtml">
                <action method="addJs"><script>your_script.js</script></action>
            </block>
        </reference>
    </reference>
</catalog_product_view>
```

`Category:`

```
<catalog_category_default translate="label">
    <reference name="root">
        <reference name="before_document_end">
            <block type="page/html_head" name="jsfooter" as="jsfooter" template="page/html/jsfooter.phtml">
                <action method="addJs"><script>your_script.js</script></action>
            </block>
        </reference>
    </reference>
</catalog_category_default>
```

`Search:`

```
<catalogsearch_result_index translate="label">
    <reference name="root">
        <reference name="before_document_end">
            <block type="page/html_head" name="jsfooter" as="jsfooter" template="page/html/jsfooter.phtml">
                <action method="addJs"><script>your_script.js</script></action>
            </block>
        </reference>
    </reference>
</catalogsearch_result_index>
```

I tested adding a block to the end of the document on Magento 1.8, but only referenced [this](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/355/move-all-javascript-includes-to-before-body) for how to add a script inside a block easily, so make sure you test it out.

Comment: Just to confirm. It appears you need to reference all the catalog page types (view, search, category) seperately like in your example. There is no way to do it with a single entry??

Comment: As far as my knowledge goes, I know no other way than adding it in each individual section. If you were to do a single entry it would be loaded on every page. You could use javascript to detect the domain for each of the locations you require and then load your script, but that goes against the way Magento is setup.