# Trouble adding JS to before body end without modifying Magento theme

Tags: blocks, module, ce-1.9.1.0

I need to add javascript to just before the closing body tag. [Move all Javascript includes to before </body>](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/355/move-all-javascript-includes-to-before-body) has is a solution but it seems to me that overriding page/html/footer.phtml will cause my module to be incompatible many themes and will take away from the automation of a simple install/uninstall.

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you looking to move default Magento js files or additional/custom js files to before the </body> ?

Comment: No, I am just hoping to add an additional location to insert after-content JS.

Answer (score 3):

Try adding this to your layout XML file.

```
<default>
    <reference name="before_body_end">
        <block type="core/text" name="filename.js">
            <action method="setText">
                <text><![CDATA[<script type="text/javascript" src="skin/frontend/YOUR_PACKAGE/YOUR_THEME/js/filename.js"></script>]]></text>
            </action>
        </block>
    </reference>
</default>
```

Be sure to replace both instances of 'filename.js'. You may also need to flush Magento's caches to see the changes.  If the javascript file is located in the main js folder it may be easier to load as you won't have to worry about updating 'YOUR_PACKAGE' and 'YOUR_THEME' but this is up to you.