# Adding JavaScript before closing body tag (</body>)

Tags: magento-1.9, javascript

I'm quite new to Magento (ver 1.9.1.0). I'm trying to add a JavaScript just before the closing `</body>` tag.

I've read other questions about this but none of them seem to work in my situation. Some said that I can edit `footer.phtml` but I wouldn't want to do that. As much as possible, I want to do it via `page.xml` located at `/app/design/frontend/THEME/PACKAGE/layout`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Move all Javascript includes to before </body>](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/355/move-all-javascript-includes-to-before-body)

Comment: I think that moves ALL of the javascript before </body>. In my case, I just want to add a JavaScript code before </body>. Well anyway I'll still give that one a try and see if it will work. Thanks @QaisarSatti.

Comment: if you want to add only js code then i prefer use `system > configuration > design > Footer  > Miscellaneous HTML ` add your js here it will add `</body>` tag

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to do it with layout XML instead of the system configuration, for example because you are developing an extension or only need it on certain pages, use the `before_body_end` container. You can put the JavaScript in a template:

```
<reference name="before_body_end">
    <block type="core/template" name="any_unique_name_here" template="path/to/your/template.phtml" />
</reference>
```

Or add it as a text block directly in XML:

```
<reference name="before_body_end">
    <block type="core/text" name="any_unique_name_here">
        <action method="setText">
            <text><![CDATA[
<script type="text/javascript">
console.log('It works!');
</script>
]]></text>
        </action>
    </block>
</reference>
```

Comment: 1 Kudos from me :)

Comment: I tried the first one and it worked. Thanks for this!

Comment: how did you do this, i cant get it working

Answer (score 6):

if you want to add only js code then i prefer use `system > configuration > design > Footer  > Miscellaneous HTML` add your js here it will add `</body>` tag

Comment: I tried and it is working fine. Thanks for sharing @Qaisar...