# Exclude particular <script> tag moving to bottom of the page- Magento 2.3

Tags: magento2.3, script, speedoptimization

In my Magento site, we found there was configuration in admin.

Admin -> Store -> Configuration -> Advanced -> Developer (Enabled only on Developer mode).
JavaScript settings -> Move JS code to the bottom of the page

When this is YES, all the scripts tags on the site moves to the bottom of the page.

But I need to include a script which shouldn't move to the bottom.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: follow this link https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/355/move-all-javascript-includes-to-before-body and yes i know this link is magento 1 but you are include js file in xml file.And some edit xml file add `before.body.end`

Comment: Thanks for your Update. My scripts loads in via phtml. And I need to load avoid that particular script from moving to bottom.

Comment: Id recommend using MageFan module rather than the magento built in one as it is buggy https://magefan.com/rocket-javascript-deferred-javascript this allows you to acheive what you are after

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have developed a solution on my own. And submitted this as a blog.

Hope this helps for someone.

https://www.dckap.com/blog/exclude-script-from-magento-2-3/

Happy Coding..!!!

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

To exclude a particular  tag from moving to the bottom of the page, simply add `type="text/x-magento-template"` to the script tag and it will remain where originally inserted via layout instruction.

See `vendor\magento\module-theme\Controller\Result\JsFooterPlugin.php`

Line 82:: `$isXMagentoTemplate = strpos($script, 'text/x-magento-template') !== false;`

Answer (score 0):

Edit the `JsFooterPlugin.php` file in `/vendor/magento/module-theme/Controller/Result` and include an exception in the first conditional of ***public function beforeSendResponse***

Answer (score 0):

You can fix it by adding text/x-magento-template to that script.
Example: < script exclude-this-tag="text/x-magento-template">