# What are some best practices for optimizing the front end performance of an Adobe Commerce store, with an emphasis on increasing lighthouse scores?

Tags: magento2, frontend, performance, optimization, pagespeed

For someone looking to increase the front end speed and optimize the front end performance of an Adobe Commerce store, with an emphasis on lighthouse scores, what would be some good starting points to emphasize?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some great starting points for someone looking to increase the front end speed and optimize the front end performance of an Adobe Commerce store, with an emphasis on lighthouse scores, are these:

1. Merge CSS => https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/commerce-admin/config/advanced/developer.html
2. Minify CSS => https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/commerce-admin/config/advanced/developer.html
3. Minify JS => https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/commerce-admin/config/advanced/developer.html
4. Move JS to the bottom of the page => https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/commerce-admin/config/advanced/developer.html
5. Enable Critical CSS => https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/frontend-core/guide/css/critical-path
6. Create unique Critical CSS per page => https://github.com/Joshua34/CriticalCSSPerPage
7. Add Assets to CSP Whitelist => https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/php/development/security/content-security-policies/#configure-csps-for-your-custom-codeextensiontheme
8. Lazy load all below-the-fold images => https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Performance/Lazy_loading#images_and_iframes
9. Add `fetchpriority="high"` to LCP element => https://web.dev/priority-hints/
10. Add `<link rel="preload">` to  for LCP & all critical assets => https://web.dev/preload-critical-assets/
11. Add `<link rel="preconnect">` to  for any external critical assets => https://developer.chrome.com/en/docs/lighthouse/performance/uses-rel-preconnect/
12. As needed, exclude any critical scripts from being moved => https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/363633/5880
13. Install, generate, bundle, and enable MagePack => https://github.com/magesuite/magepack
14. Add `<link rel="preload">` to `<head>` for all generated magepack files
15. Reduce unused CSS => https://developer.chrome.com/en/docs/lighthouse/performance/unused-css-rules/
16. Filter all scripts and GTM tags to run on an "as needed" basis only
17. Ensure all scripts and external resources are running most up-to-date version
18. Filter any font libraries loaded, remove unused glyphs => https://web.dev/font-best-practices/
19. Add `<link rel="preload">` to `<head>` for all external fonts => https://web.dev/optimize-webfont-loading/
20. Install & configure varnish => https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/commerce-operations/configuration-guide/cache/varnish/config-varnish.html
21. Serve cached resources to visitors => https://developer.chrome.com/en/docs/lighthouse/performance/uses-long-cache-ttl/
22. If using cloudlfare, enable webp support => https://developers.cloudflare.com/images/polish/activate-polish
23. Use http/2 delivery for all assets => https://www.cloudflare.com/learning/performance/http2-vs-http1.1/
24. Run Magento in Production Mode => https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/commerce-operations/configuration-guide/setup/application-modes.html
25. Cleanup site database
26. Remove any and all unused 3rd party modules, scripts, fonts
27. Check code for any duplicate calls to assets, scripts, fonts, styling rules
28. Fix any console errors
29. Fix any HTML code errors => https://validator.w3.org/
30. Add `<link rel="prefetch">` (after browser idle) for anticipated resources => https://web.dev/link-prefetch/

Following these steps allowed me to improve my lighthouse score from a 49 to a 96.